# How to remove outside UIViews from UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8, ios9

I have added multiples UIViews on outside of UIViewController and all views have week outlet connected. How can i Release memory of all view when pop to back ViewController.[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you not using ARC??

Comment: Are you getting any memory warnings??

Comment: If it is weak, you don't have to worry about, I believe.

Comment: No, i am not using ARC. i used MVC.

Comment: Not getting Memory warning but memory not reduced when i pop back.

Comment: How it can be reduced ldindu.

Answer (score 2):

First: Views (or other objects) on the top level of a xib should not have a `weak` kind of property in their corresponding view controller. Unlike view's in the view hierarchy, they don't have an owner after the xib is loaded and so they get deallocated anyway.

Now you seem to use ivars directly (*why?*), so I am actually not sure, but I don't think that makes a difference. Assuming Interface Builder accepts those as outlets and sets them, they're gone soon without an owner.

From that point of view, you've already saved memory...

Without knowing more about your project I can't tell, but the fact you're not asking for help on running into `nil` problems makes me guess you're taking ownership of these views somewhere else. To free them, you need to set whatever property (you *are* hopefully soon using properties for this) refers to them strongly to `nil`. ARC does the rest for you. Not using ARC? Start using it...

I would recommend to restructure this. Give the view controller (I guess that's some kind of `FirstFlyerViewController`) strong *properties* to the views (if you definitely need to have them outside the view hierarchy, otherwise, just add them as subviews somewhere). Use them, and once you pop the view controller *and* it gets dealloced (note that this is usually done by the framework and not yourself) they get freed along with it.

Comment: i appreciate but i am not using ARC.. how can i removed all of views without ARC?

Comment: If you're not using ARC you shouldn't be using the `__strong` and `__weak` keywords, they're conceptually belonging to ARC (were introduced with it). I'm surprised the compiler doesn't complain. To give up ownership of the views you send them a release message: `[aView release]`. But as I said, that assumes you *do* have ownership somewhere. The screenshots imply you don't have. I'd strongly recommend to rethink your xib and app structure. Also think about using properties.